# I wants to convey to the call receiver user that "your voice is being recorded" in voice format

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-twiml, voice-recording, call-recording

I am working on a call recording app and I wants to convey to the call receiver user that "your voice is being recorded" in voice format.
Note: I am asking this query because, my app has been rejected from apple store with following message.
Guideline 2.5.14 - Performance - Software Requirements
We found that your app records the user but does not have the proper indicators that the app is recording, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
**Specifically, your app records phone conversations but does not have an auditory indicator heard by all parties on the call that the app is recording.**

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you use Twilio in your iOS app (please add code to your question) but the TwiML for a custom text to speech that is read back to the caller is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>your voice is being recorded</Say>
</Response>
```

See the [Twilio doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say).

You'd need to insert this TwiML before interacting with the user.

Comment: I want voice message to be heard by call receiver after just picking up the call @yvesonline

Comment: How are you handling the call? Do you have a webhook? Are you issuing it within the iOS app? How are you using Twilio within the iOS app? I'll need to know the method and ideally some code you're using before I can give any advice.

Comment: I am using Twilio Studio flow , and twilio phone number to be linked with that Twillio studio, and phone number calling from ios app, it having massive settings to do for that